# $_FILES doesn't work

Tags: php, file-upload

my script doesn't work in producton environment. The current permission is 777 for folders and files in this test case.

index.php

```
   <form action="file.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="file[]" value=""/>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
   </form>
```

file.php

```
   var_dump($_FILES);
   die();
```

the result is: array(0) { }

It works perfectly in wamp server, only in the website host doesn't work.

Comment: Check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` on your server configuration, maybe your file exeeds that limit.

Comment: Could that directory have different permissions? maybe part of another virtualhost? did you check `.htaccess`?

Comment: @AlmirJúnior, the code is correct. Checked out without any modifications.

Comment: Betting that if you removed `[]`, it'll work.